# Trim trailing lines and remove blank lines in C

Tags: c, unix

This simple program, that I call `trim(1)`, trims trailing lines and, if the flag `-l` is passed as an argument, it also removes empty lines and lines containing only blanks.

I did this as an exercise for learning C and good practices of C programming in UNIX.

It reads from standard input if no argument is passed or read from the files passed as arguments.

I am a bit suspicious of that realloc idiom for reallocing the buffer if it gets full. Is it right?

```
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MID 0   /* in middle of line */
#define BEG 1   /* at beginning of line */

static int blankline = 0;
static int exitval = EXIT_SUCCESS;

static void trim(FILE *fp);
static void usage(void);

/* remove trailing blanks and delete blank lines */
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch;
    FILE *fp;

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "l")) != -1) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'l':
            blankline = 1;
            break;
        default:
            usage();
            break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    if (argc == 0) {
        trim(stdin);
    } else {
        while (*argv) {
            if ((fp = fopen(*argv, "r")) == NULL) {
                warn("%s", *argv);
                exitval = EXIT_FAILURE;
            } else {
                trim(fp);
                fclose(fp);
            }
            argv++;
        }
    }
}

/* trim trailing blanks from fp; if blankline is set also remove blank lines */
static void
trim(FILE *fp)
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t i, size, newsize;
    int status;
    int c;

    size = BUFSIZ;

    if (buf == NULL)
        if ((buf = malloc(size)) == NULL)
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "malloc");

    i = 0;
    status = BEG;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {

        if (isblank(c)) {               /* collect blanks in buf */
            if (i >= size) {            /* realloc */
                newsize = size + BUFSIZ;
                if (newsize <= size)    /* check for overflow */
                    errc(EXIT_FAILURE, EOVERFLOW, "realloc");
                size = newsize;
                if ((buf = realloc(buf, size)) == NULL)
                    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "realloc");
            }
            buf[i++] = c;
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            if (status == MID || (!blankline))
                putchar('\n');
            status = BEG;
            i = 0;
        } else {
            fwrite(buf, 1, i, stdout);
            putchar(c);
            status = MID;
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (ferror(fp)) {
        warn("getc");
        exitval = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}

/* show usage */
static void
usage(void)
{
    (void)fprintf(stderr, "usage: trim [-l] [file...]\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well designed code.

---

> I am a bit suspicious of that realloc idiom for reallocing the buffer if it gets full. Is it right?

I see no errors.

Nit: I'd rather see `newsize` declared locally.  It is only used there.

```
// newsize = size + BUFSIZ;
size_t newsize = size + BUFSIZ;
```

---

Other

**Unneeded code**

The initial allocation is not needed.  `realloc()` in the loop can handle starting from 0

```
//size = BUFSIZ;
//if (buf == NULL)
//    if ((buf = malloc(size)) == NULL)
//      err(EXIT_FAILURE, "malloc");
size = 0;
```

Perhaps there is a concern about ...

```
fwrite(NULL, 1, 0, stdout);
```

... yet given the spec "If size or nmemb is zero, fwrite returns zero and the state of the stream remains unchanged.", I see no issue.

Either way I'd consider the micro-optimization below, just for the sake of avoiding the `fwite()` function call as `i==0` will be quite common.  (Usually I do not encourage any micro-op - I'll make an exception here)

```
// fwrite(buf, 1, i, stdout);
if (i > 0) fwrite(buf, 1, i, stdout);
```

**Checking output**

Code does not check the return values of `fwrite(), putchar(c)`.  Robust code would and report the problem - even if it is rare.

**Missing `free()`**

Free the allocation, else `trim()` leaks memory.

```
free(buf);
```

**`ferror()`**

Good that code checks this.

**`main()` always reports success**

`main()` employs the implied `return 0;`.  Yet failure is possible.

Given code has `exitval = EXIT_FAILURE;`, I'd expect `main()` to `return exitval;` in the end.

**Initialize**

Rather than declare then assign lines later, consider declare with initialization.

```
// int status;
// ...
// status = BEG;
int status = BEG;

// size_t size;
// ...
// size = BUFSIZ;
size_t size = BUFSIZ;
```

Same for `i`.

Comment: *"Given code has exitval = EXIT_FAILURE;, I'd expect main() to return exitval; in the end."*  LOL, it was supposed to `return exitval`, I really forgot it. Thanks for seeing it!

Comment: *"Code does not check the return values of fwrite(), putchar(c)"*. Should I use an `ferror(stdout)` in the end of the function instead of checking the return values of `fwrite(3)` and `putchar(3)`?

Comment: @barthooper Perhaps.  A more direct approach would take action as soon as the error occurs.  IMO a write error is most likely on the first write - otherwise it is rare.  Your call.